# SQL Multiple table Join Query

Tags: sql

I have two tables, `College_Infra_items` and `College_infrastructure`.

The `College_Infra_items` table has the following structure and sample data:

```
col_infraId  requiredSeat  available collegeInfrastructureId collegeId
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
   1         100              150           1                   2
   2         200              180           2                   2
   3         200              160           3                   3
   4         300              190           4                   3
```

`College_infrastructure` has the following structure and sample data:

```
collegeInfrastructureId  type    name
--------------------------------------------------------------
     1                   UGC     Land Requirement(In acres)
     2                   UGC     Class rooms
     3                   UGC     Total Area
     4                   UGC     Loans
```

Right now I am writing query like this

```
SELECT 
    ci.collegeInfrastructureId as collegeInfrastructureId,
    ci.type as type, ci.name as name,
    cli.requiredSeat as requiredSeat,
    cli.available as available   
FROM 
    college_infrastructure ci
LEFT JOIN 
    College_Infra_items cli ON cli.collegeInfrastructureId = ci.collegeInfrastructureId
WHERE 
    ci.type=:type AND cli.collegeId=:collegeId
ORDER BY 
    ci.collegeInfrastructureId ASC";
```

I am trying to display all rows from `college_infrastructure` table that is names column and whichever rows that are filled in required seat and available columns from `college_infraitems` table. But now it is returning only filled details from both tables. Irrespective of `collegeId`, I need to get all rows that is all names by type from the `college_infrastructure` table. But only two rows are returned because of the condition in where clause where I mentioned `collegeId`.

If college id=2 then it returns only two rows. I need to display all names from `college_infrastructure` table and filled data from `college_infraitems` table. Can anyone tell how to achieve this?

Comment: first of all use inner join instead of left..and then you can have controll over full data, use appropriate condition then to filter data..

Comment: Left justified SQL is so hard to read...

Comment: Your LEFT JOIN executes as a regular inner join. Move cli.collegeId=:collegeId to the ON clause to get left join result.

Comment: Yup its working now.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *first* table go into the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on the *second* table go in the `ON` clause; otherwise, the outer join is turned into an inner join:

```
SELECT ci.collegeInfrastructureId, ci.type, ci.name,
       cli.requiredSeat, cli.available   
FROM college_infrastructure ci LEFT JOIN
     college_Infra_items cli
     ON cli.collegeInfrastructureId = ci.collegeInfrastructureId AND
        cli.collegeId = :collegeId
WHERE ci.type = :type 
ORDER BY ci.collegeInfrastructureId asc;
```

In addition, you don't need to use `as` to rename a column back to the same name it has.  So, `ci.type` is going to be called `type` by default.  No need to clutter the query with `ci.type as type`.